# How to show marker position on google map in real time and avoid time inaccuracy of setTimeout and setInterval?

Tags: google-maps, animation, settimeout, setinterval

I am able to animate marker along the polyline by changing offset or just by setPosition and array of latlng. But it involves using setInterval or setTimeout functions. And they can not guaranty exact timing based of their nature (CPU load, other processes in queue and so on). How can I compensate that time inaccuracy and show real time position of marker?

Add some code to above question:

function  animateMarker(path,runts) {

```
var pcur = 1,
    acur = 1,
    totaltime = runts[runts.length-1] - runts[0],
    newPos = [];

for (var t1=1; t1 < path.length; t1++) {
    var timegap = Math.round((runts[t1] - runts[t1-1])/totaltime*100),
        latint = path[t1].lat() - path[t1-1].lat(),
        lngint = path[t1].lng() - path[t1-1].lng();
    for (var t2=1; t2 <= timegap; t2++) {
        newPos[pcur] = new google.maps.LatLng( path[t1-1].lat()+t2/timegap*latint, path[t1-1].lng()+t2/timegap*lngint );
        pcur++;
    }
}
var animateId = setInterval(function() {
    myMarker.setPosition(newPos[acur]);
    acur++;
    if (acur == pcur) clearInterval(animateId);
}, 20);
```

}

20 millisec in setInterval should make the whole animation last for 2sec (20*100), but in reality all depend on CPU load and decreasing 20ms to 5ms will not give any changes...
How can I use time() function to animate tracker based on real ts from runts array?

Comment: setTimeout and setInterval are the only way. But in your code, instead of assuming that the delays from them are constant, use the current time in milliseconds to determine the position

Comment: thank you for your answer. I also think I should use time() to animate in real time, but real example would be helpful...